# laravel notification on slack channel webkook

Tags: slack-api

An app that sends HTTP request to any URL and records the response in the database, if in case there is a response that website is dawn, it should automatical save the response and send a message into a slack channel. the first question is which library to use to integrate slack with laravel>

Answer (score 1):

There numerous slack-api wrappers in PHP. But these two are some of the most expressive:

- https://github.com/vluzrmos/laravel-slack-api
- https://github.com/maknz/slack

Follow through the README and see which fits best your needs.

Comment: thanks alot. the first one seems to work better , but  there were two issues,

Comment: The first one is after i configured all the steps, i tried to create controller from the terminal called Your controller, in order to create dependency injection i.e php artisan make:controller YourController. it gave an error "classs must be a valid object or a string". so that means i can put the php dependency injection...... more over where to put the usage part in larval, should a create a new class in app/http/route?

Comment: Maybe you should open an issue in that repository. They could be able to help you there.